# My ubuntu system takes long to boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have Ubuntu 19.04 it worked fine until i installed the Canta theme for it and still it worked fine for 3 days than i turn on the system and it takes 35 minutes to boot and now all there is black screen after 5 hours of booting. Please help what should i do ? I have tried letting it boot for the whole night  the but there is still the black screen.After sometime a person from the Ubuntu community told me to use CLT-ALT-F3 than it booted immediately for 3 days than the the 4th day nothing happened and the black screen came back and it did not boot the whole night again. My question is that should I reset anything with the advanced options for Ubuntu when it boots asks me choose between Windows or Ubuntu. ?

My system specs : 
CPU = Intel i3-5005U @ 2.00G and its duel core 
RAM = 8GB dual channel memory 
Hardisk = 1TB Hdd

Please help me with the solution....
Thank you,
Jayden

Comment: Press Esc, does anything happen? Press Ctrl + Alt + F3, does anything happen?

Comment: Yes it worked !

Comment: Should I do the same if it happens again or do I have to r

Comment: Prevent it from happening again?

Comment: We don't know what you did, and how it helped.

Comment: All i did was install the canta theme from the terminal and the ram is also upgraded for you knowledge

Comment: and now that also dose not work.

Comment: and totally forgot tell it the PC is duel booted with windows 8.1 home. should i do anything in the booting menu ? or in the advanced ubuntu options

Comment: Please update your question. Does your system still show a black screen, or take 35 minutes of booting? What did you do that helped? At present, your question plus the comments are a jumble of loose ends.

Comment: Yes I updated it

Comment: Can someone help me with the solution